# SQLite - Check for an empty column and retrieve column name

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm currently working at a SQL statement which checks in a table whether a column is empty or not.

If its empty it should return me the name of the column which I need for shifting the visibility-property.

Anybody have an advice for this issue?

Greetings and thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check *all* values in a column, you can do something like:

```
select (case when max(col1) is null then 1 else 0 end) as col1_is_empty,
       (case when max(col2) is null then 1 else 0 end) as col2_is_empty,
       (case when max(col3) is null then 1 else 0 end) as col3_is_empty
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what language you are using, this would help get you started:

In a table called SysUsers with columns Id, Username, Cellphone, Email, this will do what you want:

```
select ifnull(Username, 'Username is null') Username,
 ifnull(Cellphone, 'Cellphone is null') Cellphone,
 ifnull(Email, 'Email is null') Email
 from SysUsers where Id = 476
```

This is however not the best way to do this. Why don't you rather loop though the columns in code to check for nulls?